# not able to locate missing ) ..... Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: apex

I am trying to make outputpanel dependent on if condition but it says i am missing ) which i am not getting

```
           <div>
              <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(mapOfPaymentRecord.get('StudentDetails').nm_Lead__r.Permanent_State__c == '', TRUE, FALSE)}" >
                <p>Some message.......Here will heasn hba kah jv javh gh jhak gvgjchj hav vh bvjhv j hb hh h vavjh vhjv</p>
              </apex:outputPanel>

            </div>
```

Comment: Try replacing `.get('StudentDetails')` with `['StudentDetails']`.

Comment: See this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_maps_lists.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maps in Visualforce require square brackets to access values and you don't need the `IF`:

```
rendered="{! mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Permanent_State__c == '' }"
```